# External Item Picker problems in InfoPath 2010 with ECT

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, external-content-type

I have used SPD to create and ECT to a standard SQL Database, and then a view.  In the view there is an ID field, and then another field of a string type that stores codes (consisting mainly of numbers, but some number and letter combinations do exist).

On the ECT I have created a "Read List" operation with a limit filter and a filter to return values based on the code column.

I have setup an InfoPath form that uses the external item picker and uses the ECT.  When I test the form and use the second button from the left of the picker, the "Select external item(s)", a pop-up dialog appears and I can search for and select an item just fine.

When I enter a code directly into the external item pickers text box and then click the "Check if external item exists" button it works but instead of then underlining the code (to indicate it was correct) it returns the id of that row and underlines that.

No matter how I try to alter the settings of the external item picker in InfoPath or the ECT in SPD can I get it to work.

Do I have to revert to code and create my own finder method rather than using the out of the box features of SPD to get this to work as I want?

Also, are the names of the filters set in the SPD wizard for creating the "Read List" operation the finder methods I should be referencing in the external item picker properties?

Comment: bump! I am having same issue. This is exacly same issue.

Answer (score 1):

(You probably don't need this answer any more, but I'll put it up in case anyone else comes across this question.)

Open up the External Item Picker properties and go to the General tab. The field you want is "Display Field Name." If the column you want to show in the picker is called RecordTitle, then type RecordTitle into "Display Field Name" and you should be all set.